# Referring to object from external file error

Tags: python, oop, object, pyqt

In my GUI I am trying to add a widget to a HBox layout from an external file. I would like to do this so my project becomes cleaner.

**Error**

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "__main__.py", line 26, in <module>
    w = GUI()
  File "__main__.py", line 15, in __init__
    frames.stopVerification()
  File "/home/jarno/python/test/frames.py", line 12, in stopVerification
    __main__.w.principalLayout.addWidget(stopVerificationFrame)
AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute 'w'
```

I don't understand why the module **main** has no attribute w, because actually created an instance **w** of class **GUI**.

I've made a simplified code for you:

**Main file:**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QFrame, QGridLayout, QHBoxLayout, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QWidget)

import frames

class GUI(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(GUI, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        self.principalLayout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.controlFrame = QFrame(self) 
        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(self.controlFrame)
        self.principalLayout.addWidget(self.controlFrame)

        self.widgets()

        frames.stopVerification()
    def widgets(self):
        self.bStart = QPushButton('Start')
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.bStart, 0, 0)

        self.bStop = QPushButton('Stop')
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.bStop, 0, 2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)    
    w = GUI()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

frames file:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QFrame, QGridLayout, QHBoxLayout, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QWidget)

import gui

def stopVerification(): 
        stopVerificationFrame = QFrame()
        horizontalLayout = QHBoxLayout(stopVerificationFrame)

        bDesktop = QPushButton("Desktop")
        horizontalLayout.addWidget(bDesktop)

        gui.w.principalLayout.addWidget(stopVerificationFrame)
```

Comment: `w` is not created before `GUI` is returned. `gui.w` is access while `GUI` is in call.

Comment: Why don't you pass the main GUI as an argument to the function ( `stopVerification(self)` ) and instead import the gui file and refer to global variables?

Comment: Thanks @alexblae I didn't knew this.

Comment: Also thank you @falsetru it makes total sense now.